# Как заставить программу проверять порядок возрастания цифр в числе?

Tags: python

Дана 25 задача ЕГЭ:

Назовём маской числа последовательность цифр, в которой также могут встречаться следующие символы:
— символ «?» означает ровно одну произвольную цифру;
— символ «*» означает любую последовательность цифр произвольной длины; в том числе «*» может задавать и пустую последовательность.
Среди натуральных чисел, не превышающих 10^9, найдите все числа, соответствующие маске `1*5*9`, значения разрядов в которых идут в строго возрастающем порядке, и делящиеся на 21 без остатка. В ответе запишите в первом столбце таблицы все найденные числа в порядке возрастания, а во втором столбце — соответствующие им частные от деления на 21.
Количество строк для ввода ответа избыточно

Вот мой код:

```
from fnmatch import *
for i in range(21, 10**9):
    if fnmatch(str(i), '1*5*9'):
        a = str(i)
        for x in range(len(a)-1):
            if a[x]<a[x+1]:
                print(i, i//21)
```

Правильный ответ не выдает, что я делаю не так?

Comment: А что выдает программа?

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy, кучу чисел, которые сличает в течении полторы минуты

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что маска "1*5*9" эквивалентна маске "9", потому что `*` - это даже пустая последовательность? т.е. найти надо все числа у которых последняя цифра 9 дополнительные условия?

Comment: Вам надо проверить 64 числа - восемь вариантов в первой звёздочке и восемь во второй. Думайте.
Ещё вы потеряли проверку на делимость. Ещё печатаете каждое число и по многу раз.

Comment: @Zhihar, это другие звёздочки, не регулярные.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вариант не проверяет делимость на 21 и печатает много лишних чисел, и каждое много раз. Вот как его можно доработать:

```
from fnmatch import *


for i in range(21, 10 ** 9 + 1, 21):
    a = str(i)
    if fnmatch(a, '1*5*9'):
        for x in range(len(a) - 1):
            if a[x] >= a[x + 1]:
                break
        else:
            print(i, i // 21)
```

Теперь код проверяет примерно 50 миллионов чисел:

> ```
> $ time python numbers.py
> 12579 599
> 123459 5879
> 134589 6409
> 1234569 58789
> 1356789 64609
>
> real  0m53.956s
> user  0m53.112s
> sys   0m0.016s
> ```

Достаточно проверить 64 числа. Как может выглядеть подстановка первой звёздочки? Если учесть что цифры должны расти, то: 15, 1**2**5, 1**3**5, 1**4**5, 1**23**5, 1**24**5, 1**34**5, 1**234**5 - восемь вариантов:

```
def substrings(s):
    if s == '':
        yield ''
    else:
        for t in substrings(s[1:]):
            yield t
            yield s[0] + t


def numbers():
    for p1 in substrings('234'):
        for p2 in substrings('678'):
            n = int(f'1{p1}5{p2}9')
            if n % 21 == 0:
                yield n


for i in sorted(numbers()):
    print(i, i // 21)
```

Эта программа проверяет 64 числа мгновенно.

> ```
> $ time python numbers.py
> 12579 599
> 123459 5879
> 134589 6409
> 1234569 58789
> 1356789 64609
>
> real  0m0.028s
> user  0m0.024s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```